# Entity Framework Core 7 apply custom ValueConverter to Inserts and Updates

Tags: valueconverter, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I am struggling to understand how to apply a custom ValueConverter to all the properties of all the models before every insert and update.

According to this resource it can be done:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

"Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading from or **writing ** to the database"

I was able to accomplish this, but only when reading from the database, overriding ConfigureConventions in the Context:

```
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().HaveConversion<ToUpperConverter>();
    }
```

Converter

```
    public class ToUpperConverter : ValueConverter<string, string>
    {
        public ToUpperConverter() : base(v => v, v => v.Trim().ToUpper())
        {
        }
    }
```

Tried also to override the method SaveChangesAsync in the Context, this works but obviously I don't want to go manually for every property and for every model considering they can change at every time.
Using reflection here can be an option, but I am not really a big fan of it.

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Player>())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Entity.Name = entry.Entity.Name.ToUpper();
            entry.Entity.MiddleName = entry.Entity.MiddleName?.ToUpper();
            entry.Entity.Surname = entry.Entity.Surname.ToUpper();
        }
    }
   return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved, after spending on this an entire day..
The first argument of the converter is the conversion happening to the database, the second argument is the conversion happening from the database.

```
public class ToUpperConverter : ValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public ToUpperConverter() : base(
        // writing to the database
        v => v.Trim().ToUpper(),
       // reading from the database
       v => v.Trim().ToUpper())
    {
    }
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertiesconfigurationbuilder.haveconversion?view=efcore-6.0

"The type to convert to and from or a type that inherits from ValueConverter."